# Display content from tinymcewith images

Tags: image, file, tinymce, document, dompdf

I am building a document management systems that allows users to create document using Tinymce. Users can add images to the document then saving the document will automatically generate a pdf file. I am currently using Dompdf but the problem is the pdf does not display images added to the document. It only displays content of the document for images are not displaying.

Below is the codes that generate the pdf

```html
$doc = Documentrole::find($id);
            $pdfPath = 'pdf/' . str_random(5) . '.pdf';
            $view = View('documents.dg.myPDF', ['docs' => $doc]);
            $pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');

            $pdf->getDomPDF()->setBasePath(public_path());

            $pdf->getDomPDF()->setHttpContext(
                stream_context_create([
                    'ssl' => [
                        'allow_self_signed'=> TRUE,
                        'verify_peer' => FALSE,
                        'verify_peer_name' => FALSE,
                    ]
                ])
              );
             $pdf = \PDF::setOptions(['isHTML5ParserEnabled' => true, 'isRemoteEnabled' => true]);
             $pdf->setOptions([
                'enable_remote' => true,
                'chroot'  => public_path('storage/uploads/'),
            ]);


            //$pdf = \PDF::setOptions(['isHtml5ParserEnabled' => true, 'isRemoteEnabled' => true]);
            $pdf->loadHTML($view->render())->save($pdfPath );
            $doc->path = $pdfPath;
            $doc->save();
```